# Typescript literal unions

Tags: typescript

I have two literal types, and I want to exclude B from union A.

```
type A = 'a' | 'b'
type B = 'a'
```

When I do it like this:

```
type MyExclude<A2, B2> = A2 extends B2 ? never : A2
type C2 = MyExclude<A, B>
// C2 = 'b'
```

It works correctly, i.e. i get 'b'.

But when I do it directly like this:

```
type C = A extends B ? never : A
// C = 'a' | 'b'
```

It doesn't. Why should it matter whether I do it via a intermediary generic type or directly?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) directy from typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do it as a generic, Typescript is going to apply the check distributively to each member of the union. So `type C2 = MyExclude<A, B>` is going to be evaluated not as `'a | b' extends 'a' ? never : 'a | 'b'`, but rather `('a' extends 'a' ? never : 'a') | ('b' extends 'a' ? never : 'b')`. 'a' does extend B, so that results in `never`. 'b' does not extend B, so that results in 'b'. And the final result is `never | 'b'`, which is just `'b'`.

The distributive part does not happen if it's not a generic. `type C = A extends B ? never : A` is just going to be evaluated once, as `'a | b' extends 'a' ? never : 'a | 'b'`. `'a' | 'b'` does not extend `'a'`, so the result is the whole type, `'a' | 'b'`

See [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types)

> Distributive conditional types
>
> Conditional types in which the checked type is a naked type parameter are called distributive conditional types. Distributive conditional types are automatically distributed over union types during instantiation. For example, an instantiation of `T extends U ? X : Y` with the type argument `A | B | C` for `T` is resolved as `(A extends U ? X : Y) | (B extends U ? X : Y) | (C extends U ? X : Y)`.